# Is there a way to specify an enum-class value without having to type out its scope every time?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, namespaces

I have some functions that can return either success or one of a fixed set of error codes.  To identify the error codes, I had (something like) this old-school C-style enum declared:

```
enum {
   RESULT_ERROR_BAD_PARAMETER = -3,
   RESULT_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = -2,
   RESULT_ERROR_GENERAL = -1,
   RESULT_SUCCESS = 0
};
typedef int my_status_t;

my_status_t MyFunc();   // returns a RESULT_* value
```

This worked pretty well; the calling pattern would be something like:

```
if (MyFunc() != RESULT_SUCCESS) printf("Error!\n");
```

... however it was uncomfortably permissive about allowing implicit conversions of `my_status_t` values to int/bool/etc, allowing careless mistakes like this:

```
// Compiles but does the wrong thing at run-time -- bad!
if (MyFunc() == false) printf("Error!\n");
```

... so in my new code revision, I converted it to be an `enum class` instead:

```
enum class my_status_t {
   RESULT_ERROR_BAD_PARAMETER = -3,
   RESULT_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = -2,
   RESULT_ERROR_GENERAL = -1,
   RESULT_SUCCESS = 0
};
```

... this works great from a compile-time checking perspective; now most unintentional type-promotions are caught by the compiler, forcing the programmer to go back and do it the right way.

The only thing that bothers me is that the new syntax is tedious:  now I have to write something like:

```
if (MyFunc() != my_status_t::RESULT_SUCCESS) printf("Error!\n");
```

... at every call site -- having to type out `my_status_t::` each time is tedious and makes the code harder to read, without really adding much value (since `RESULT_SUCCESS` is sufficiently unique for my purposes on its own, anyway)

My question is, is there some kind of `using namespace my_status_t;` style directive I could use to tell the compiler to export the enum-values out of their `my_status_t` namespace, so that I could reference them without having to type the `my_status_t::` prefix all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you going to be typing a lot more of the nuisance scope-prefixes than there
are constants in the `enum class`, then it may be worth your while to go with this
way:

```
enum class result {
   ERROR_BAD_PARAMETER = -3,
   ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = -2,
   ERROR_GENERAL = -1,
   SUCCESS = 0
};

constexpr result RESULT_ERROR_BAD_PARAMETER = result::ERROR_BAD_PARAMETER;
constexpr result RESULT_FILE_NOT_FOUND = result::ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
constexpr result RESULT_ERROR_GENERAL = result::ERROR_GENERAL;
constexpr result RESULT_SUCCESS = result::SUCCESS;

result foo() {
    return RESULT_SUCCESS;
}

int main()
{
    switch (foo())
    {
        case RESULT_SUCCESS:
            ;
    }
    // ^ warning: enumeration value ‘...’ not handled in ...

    if (foo() == RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        return 0;
    }

    /* error: no match for ‘operator==’
    if (foo() == false) {
        return -1;
    }
    */
}
```

(g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11)

Answer (score 0):

Do this change:

```
enum class result {
  ERROR_BAD_PARAMETER = -3,
  ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = -2,
  ERROR_GENERAL = -1,
  SUCCESS = 0
};
```

because your enumerated values are in a scope, you no longer have to give them as long a name.

Now your code becomes:

```
if (MyFunc() != result::SUCCESS) printf("Error!\n");
```

which is a whole 1 character longer than before.

You could also

```
using my_status_t = result;
```

if you are tied to `my_status_t` as a type name.

---

As of C++17 there is no way to cleanly avoid the `result::` prefix.  There is talk about `using ERROR_BAD_PARAMETER = result::ERROR_BAD_PARAMETER;` or the like in later versions of C++, but I'm unaware if they are going to get into [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20).

Comment: What I'm looking for is the ability to avoid the `something::` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```
enum class my_status_t { };

inline constexpr my_status_t RESULT_ERROR_BAD_PARAMETER = my_status_t(-3);
// add other enum values here
```

Unfortunately, this way you lose some good properties of `enum`. Like compiler can warn you if you don't handle a value in a switch (and don't forget to set the underlying type of `enum class`, if you have big values).

So I actually don't recommend this way (I better like Yakk's solution), but maybe this answer can help you anyway...